# Problems with BURG on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: dual-boot, themes, burg

i have  installed Buc, Burg Manager and Burg works fine. When i reboot my laptop (Ubuntu 14.04 & Win 7), i get the Burg default display (nearly the same like grub). If i install and change a theme with the burg manager, it saves everything but burg emu and reboot also displays the default theme.

I have tried the GUI method by using burg manager to install BURG and themes, tried the terminal method, and also tried another GUI method by using GRUB-Optimizer, which also is able to configure BURG.

Did i forget something?

edit: I've fixed the problem. In the burg.cfg file was the absolute path to the theme, but it is enough if you write down just the theme name (if themes are installed correct). Now it works fine)